# Why Flutter Socket.connect does not work if network is changed after app startup

Tags: flutter, dart, sockets, icmp, dart-io

When using the `Socket.connect` from `dart:io` package, I can successfully connect to an ip:port that is serving an app in `NETWORK A`.

The problem:

If I am not in that specific network (`NETWORK A`) when the app starts, and instead I connect to it after app start (change the wifi from `NETWORK B` to `NETWORK A`), then the Socket connection fails.

Code Example:

```
Socket.connect(host, port, timeout: timeout).then((socket) {
  print("Success!");
}).onError((e) => print("Failure"));
```

Env:

- Flutter 3.16.5
- Dart 3.2.3
- DevTools 2.28.4

Comment: As A test, I have started the app on NETWORK A, gotten successful connection, changed to NETWORK B, gotten failure, then changed to NETWORK A again (expecting success) but continues to fail.